# Removing site-packages for corrupted paths?

Tags: package-management, python3

There is one path I need to remove that is the `site.package`. I'm unsure is it safe to remove the `site.package` for *certain* installed software, `Django,` `Virtualenv` with out breaking the system. Is `Synaptic Package Manager` needed?

Comment: The site-packages folder is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the main reason for the corrupted paths is that the motherboard on the laptop that is being used is damaged which is causing many different types of errors.

---

The way to fix this problem on good hardware does not require reinstalling Ubuntu. Open the terminal and type:

```
ls /usr/lib/python3.7
```

The results of ls `/usr/lib/python3.7` may show a directory named *site.packages*. The site.packages directory may contain several directories in it which have Python packages that you may have installed with pip3 to use in your Django project in Ubuntu 19.04 for which python3.7 is the base interpreter. Let's look at an example. Let's suppose that there is a directory in the site.packages directory named Django. If such a directory exists, then it was installed by pip3.  To uninstall this instance of Django that was installed by pip3 run:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall Django
```

Please note that you must use sudo in the above command because the `/usr/lib/python3.7/site.packages` directory is owned by root. If the site.packages directory is located in your home folder, then it is not owned by root and you don't need to use sudo to uninstall a Python package from this directory. You could uninstall a Python package from this directory with a command of the form `pip3 uninstall package-name`

Comment: Maybe you already uninstalled all the Python packages from your Django project that were installed by pip. On the other hand you may have installed the Python packages without using `sudo pip`. If so, there would be a site-packages directory in your home folder in `home/elizabeth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`

Comment: sudo pip3 uninstall Django, Not uninstalling django at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr.

Comment: A Python path to nowhere would cause the Python interpreter to ignore that path and do nothing, because if the Python interpreter finds nothing at that path it ignores the path and does nothing

Comment: Django is causing the import error on PyCharm IDE. I am running different versions of Django on PyCharm and Ubuntu .

Comment: Run the same Python code in the terminal in order to check if you get the same import error in the terminal as you got in PyCharm. The way to run a Python code block in the terminal is with IPython. To install IPython type `sudo apt install python3-ipython`. To start IPython type `ipython3`.

Comment: Have to install PyCharm IDE again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97823/discussion-between-karel-and-seemstobestuck).